# javamail load contents dynamically

Tags: java, html, email, jakarta-mail

I am sending `HTML` emails using `javamail`. I am sending emails successfully.

Now I want to send `html table` which will load the data dynamically from server. Which means I want to give link/button and after clicking, I want to get data from server and show in the table.

One option I have figured out so far is give link in email and after clicking on that open separate window/tab and show the table. But I want to show the table as a part of mail, and want to show without opening new tab/window.

My question is that is it possible? And if yes link to resources will be appreciated. If no then what are the alternate options to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my knowledge due to various security considerations, Javascript has been disabled completely in message content in many email readers. even `iframe` too. [Here is a list which supports `iframe`](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3219/do-iframes-work-in-email/) and which doesn't.

As a solution i can only think of extract the `html table` from the target server prior to sending mail and then put into the mail's message content for sending.